# Create a custom record zone in CloudKit Dashboard

Tags: ios, cloudkit

This question might seem trivial, but I'm just starting in CloudKit, and I need to be sure of the answer. Does creating a custom zone in CloudKit Dashboard creates it for all users?

I know that creating a record type will create it for everyone, since it's included in the "structure" of the database.

But I also know that creating a record in the private database will only create it for my developer account (which is logic).

What about creating a record zone in the private database? Is a record zone a component of the structure of the database, or a data itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a private database, its owner is linked to the iCloud account that the device is using. If you create a custom zone [only available on private databases] than that will be linked to the same iCloud account. 
Obviously that account will be yours when your developing, when/if you release your app on the apps store the iCloud account/zone will be the user who is using your app.
Public databases are different, they are linked to your developer account & app.

Any use of iCloud needs to be done carefully especially if you plan to release an app into the wild, so you don't caught out with quotas & charges.

Indeed if Apple deem your use of the private databases to be reckless your app won't be approved, if you make reckless use of the public database you might find yourself saddled with charges you did't bargain on.

Reckless as in your not cleaning up after yourself.